# Finding Hololens App AUMID for Kiosk Mode

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to set up multi-app kiosk mode on a Hololens headset and allow access to an app that I will be sideloading onto the Hololens.  I've been using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-kiosk) [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps) to try and create a provisioning package, but I'm stuck on the part where I need to provide an AUMID for the app.  [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app) is only useful for finding the AUMID of an app installed on a computer, how can I find it for an app installed on the Hololens, either once it is installed (using device portal), or from the finished Unity build or app package that I can generate from it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this today as I was having the exact same problem.
Device portal is the best method for HoloLens that I know of.
Let's say you wanted Feedback Hub in your Multi App Kiosk.
You go to Device Portal > Apps > find your app in the drop down (in this example, feedback hub)
PackageFullName: Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_1.1903.2331.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe

Then you remove the version number and the build architecture. As well as extra underscores.
Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Finally add on the !App
Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App

If you find a way to find the AUMID from Unity before it's installed I'd like to know it.